# Delete Post redirecting to another Route

Tags: php, post, laravel-8

This was an error that I faced while trying to Route to delete a post but was instead routed to unlike the post, I will be posting the code and where I faced the error and the solution I used, and if you could please provide me with a better solution, it would be for the best.

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="w-8/12 bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">
            <form action="{{ route('posts') }}" method="post" class="mb-4">
                @csrf
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <label for="body" class="sr-only">Body</label>
                    <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="4" class="by-gray-100 border-2
                    w-full p-4 rounded lg @error('body') border-red-500 @enderror" placeholder="Post something!"></textarea>
                    @error('body')
                        <div class="text-red-500 mt-3 text-sm">
                            {{$message}}
                        </div>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded
                    font-medium">Post</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            @if ($posts->count())
                @foreach ($posts as $post)
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <a href="" class="font-bold">{{ $post->user->username }}</a>
                        <span class="text-gray-600 text-sm">{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
                        <p class="mb-2">{{ $post->body }}</p>

                        <div>
                            <form action="{{ route('posts.destroys', $post) }}" method="post">
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            @auth
                                @if (!$post->likedBy(auth()->user()))
                                    <form action="{{ route('posts.likes', $post) }}" method="post" class="mr-1">
                                        @csrf
                                        <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Like</button>
                                    </form>
                                @else
                                    <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $post) }}" method="post" class="mr-1">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Unlike</button>
                                    </form>

                                @endif

                            @endauth
                            <span>{{ $post->likes->count() }} {{ Str::plural('likes', $post->likes->count()) }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                @endforeach

                {{ $posts->links() }}

            @else
                There are no posts...
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

The error was present here

```
<div>
     <form action="{{ route('posts.destroys', $post) }}" method="post">
      @csrf
      @method('DELETE')
      <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Delete</button>
      </form>
</div>
```

instead of posts.destroys, it was post.destroy

which redirected here

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $post) }}" method="post" class="mr-1">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Unlike</button>
</form>
```

my web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostLikeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LogoutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    //return view('welcome');
});

// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('posts.index');
// });

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
})->name('home');

Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'] )
->name('dashboard')
->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'index'] )->name('register');
Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store'] );

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'] )->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'store'] );

Route::post('/logout', [LogoutController::class, 'store'] )->name('logout');

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'] )->name('login');

Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'index'] )->name('posts');
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'] );

Route::delete('/posts{post}', [PostController::class, 'destroy'] )->name('posts.destroys');

Route::post('/posts/{post}/likes', [PostLikeController::class, 'store'] )->name('posts.likes');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}/likes', [PostLikeController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.destroy');
```

So I just changed it to destroys instead of destroy and it worked if there is a better way of doing things please let me know to avoid errors in the future...

Comment: Laravel has [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers). Your `Route::delete('/posts{post}'` seems to be missing a `/`. Also make sure that you don't have duplicate route names, `->name('posts.destroys')` seems to have been set twice

Comment: Due to the route name,  ->name('posts.destroy') being set twice that's why I added an s to the second one. Could you please tell me where my  Route::delete('/posts{post}' is missing a /

Comment: Yep, sorry, my fault, I meant `->name('posts.destroy')` has been set twice (which has been resolved already). `Route::delete('/posts{post}'` should be `Route::delete('/posts/{post}'`

Comment: Yes, it was why I added an s to one of the destroy to make it destroys